# XCODE SCM Recover discarded file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I accidentally clicked discard changes (thought I had a snapshot)... anywho, before I start up of the 7 hours of lost time, does anyone know if there is a 'trash can' or something hiding in Xcode that may have the file I discarded? Or is there any other way to get it back?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect job for Time Machine.